# Running tomcat behind multiple httpd proxy, how to log the IP of which proxy server the request goes through

Tags: apache, tomcat, ip, reverse-proxy, access-log

My system is running as architecture below

clients -> physical LB -> httpd reverse proxy (multiple servers) -> tomcat (multiple servers)

my question is how I could log the IP of the proxy server that the request goes through into the tomcat access log?

here is my tomcat server.xml config

```
  <Valve    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
            remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
            proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
            protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
  />
  <Valve    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
            requestAttributesEnabled="true"
            directory="${LOG_DIR}/tomcat"
            prefix="access."
            suffix=".log"
            pattern="%h %{org.apache.tomcat.remoteAddr}r %{X-Forwarded-For}i %A %{Host}i %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; %I %D &quot;%S&quot; &quot;%{COOKIE}i&quot;"
            resolveHosts="false"
            fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            rotatable="true"
  />
```

Comment: What does the current tomcat access log look like?